# Local storage to store unordered list items having images as children

Tags: javascript, html, css, local-storage

I am writing a simple shopping list application using html5 and JavaScript. It adds user inputs as list items and two images(done, remove) as children of li. Just wondering how to store and retrieve in localstorage. I know localstorage can only store strings and we can go around storing objects and arrays. Don't know how to convert my list items to objects or arrays so that I can store and retrieve easily.

```
var li = document.createElement('li');
 var imgDone =            document.createElement('img');
var imgRemove = document.createElement('img');
 imgDone.setAttribute('src', 'imgDone ');
 ImgRemove.setAttribute('src', imgRemove');
  li.appendChild('imgDone');
  li.appendChild('imgRemove');
  ul.appendChild(li);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JSON.stringify` to store arrays or objects.

Then to retrieve them use `JSON.parse`

Comment: Shall I do var obj = JSON.Stringify(li);